# C# how to run a process(with arguments) through an administrator elevated cmd

Tags: c#, .net, process, privileges

```
ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " +"processNeedToRun")
{
    RedirectStandardError = true,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    Verb ="runas"
};
```

I use the above code to run a process through cmd in C#.

However, the problem is:

1. "processNeedToRun" needs arguments when running.
2. Even i set Verb ="runas",  Windows 7 still prompts an elevate dialog.

Is it possible  to meet all the requirements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the process that's launching `processNeedToRun` is not elevated, then there is **no way to avoid the elevation dialog**. Doing so would be a security hole. So you're just going to have to live with the elevation prompt.

Adding arguments to `processNeedToRun` is no problem, though. You can just add them to the arguments you pass to `ProcessStartInfo`:

```
var procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c processNeedToRun arg1 arg2");
```