# launching SFC from within a C# app

Tags: c#, uac

I have been searching and I cannot seem to get this work.  I am trying to launch SFC from a button in a C# app.  I am aware that it requires rights elevation and in the scope of what I am trying to do is behavior that I want.

I have tried:
[To run cmd as administrator along with command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610727/to-run-cmd-as-administrator-along-with-command)
[Running CMD as administrator with an argument from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529713/running-cmd-as-administrator-with-an-argument-from-c-sharp)
and 
[C# how to run a process(with arguments) through an administrator elevated cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687214/c-sharp-how-to-run-a-processwith-arguments-through-an-administrator-elevated-c)

The code I tried last was:

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + "processNeedToRun")
        {
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            Verb = "runas"
        };

    }
```

I either get no process launching at all the cmd window flashes saying incorrect credentials or the command was incorrect.

what am I doing wrong?

Per the comment added I changed it to this:

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + "sfc.exe /scannow")
        {
            RedirectStandardError = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = false,
            UseShellExecute = true,
            CreateNoWindow = false,
            Verb = "runas"
        };

    }
```

and no change

EDIT:

So I managed to find a solution:

I created a new console app, edited the manifest to require admin and did this

```
Process.Start("CMD.exe", " /c SFC /Scannow");
```

That does have the behavior I want.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Added it to the original comment

Answer (score 2):

Your console is not elevating, the problem is you can either use the `Verb = "runas"` and have it elevate or you can use `UseShellExecute = false` and redirect the outputs, ***you can not have both***.

Your three options are:

1. Use `UseShellExecute = true` and disable the redirections
2. [Add a manifest file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818179/how-to-force-my-net-app-to-run-as-administrator-on-windows-7/2818776#2818776) to your program so it elevates itself as an administrator on start and it can then in turn launch administrative processes and monitor them.
3. Do a combination of both by writing a 2nd exe that has a manifest file that always runs as administrator. Then have your 1st program launch the 2nd program with `Verb = "runas"`, you then have your 2nd program start `SFC` with `UseShellExecute = false`. Your 2nd program then forwards the output via some form of IPC ([WCF over named pipes](http://tech.pro/tutorial/855/wcf-tutorial-basic-interprocess-communication) would likely be easiest) to the first unelevated program to be displayed to the user.

Comment: second app it is cause neither option 1 or 2 are launching the process.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: I apologize if I am not making myself clear.  I tried the first 2 options that you wrote in your first comment and they are not launching the process. As in cmd.exe does not run and I do not get prompted to elevate my rights.

Comment: Why are you trying to launch `cmd.exe` at all and not just do `ProcessStartInfo(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System),"sfc.exe"), "/scannow")`? (Be sure you are set to `AnyCPU` when you compile so it gets the correct `System32` folder), and did you try it with `UseShellExecute = true;` and your redirection code commented out?

Comment: I wanted the command window to show so that progress could be shown.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting 
[`ProcesStartInfo.UserName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.username%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`ProcessStartInfo.Password`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.password%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to impersonate the new process with elevated credentials.