# How to make a .ps1 file with multiple commands and Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -force?

Tags: c#, powershell, command, administrator

```
var newProcessInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
newProcessInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe";
newProcessInfo.Verb = "runas";
newProcessInfo.Arguments = @"-executionpolicy unrestricted -Command ""C:\Windows\system32\sfc.exe /scannow""";


/*
newProcessInfo.Arguments = @"-Command ""sfc /scannow""";
newProcessInfo.Arguments = @"-File ""C:\my\script.ps1""";
newProcessInfo.Arguments = @"–ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""C:\my\script.ps1"""; */
```

These are basically the basic style code commands I want to use.  I have been having a problem -executionpolicy unrestricted.  It works great when I type it in powershell just like above.

Also, what is the comparable coding in powershell to cmd.exe /k so the command prompt window stays open for troubleshooting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After seeing your error, I can say for sure that that error is coming frm the `sfc` command that you're running. The command is being executed.

Execution Policy is about how to handle script files, so it has no effect on commands run immediately (unless you reference a script file in a command). It won't help with your particular issue I'm afraid.

---

What makes you think your execution policy is not working?

Since you're not using the `-File` parameter in the uncommented code, execution policy should be irrelevant anyway.

The analogous powershell command for `cmd.exe /k` is `powershell.exe -NoExit`.

Comment: "Windows Resource Protection could not start the repair service"  That is the error that shows.  I thought the -executionpolicy unrestricted would fix this.

Comment: I turned off the trusted installer"net stop TrustedInstaller" and thought this might help, but still have the issue for "SFC /SCANNOW"

Answer (score 0):

[Answer found on Stackoverflow(click here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20871514/how-to-launch-sfc-programatically-on-windows-vista-7-8)

```
...
using System.Diagnostics;
...

private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string docs = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
    string snat = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir") + @"\sysnative\sfc.exe";

    Process a = new Process();
      a.StartInfo.FileName = snat;
      a.StartInfo.Arguments = "/SCANNOW";
      a.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
      a.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
      a.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
      a.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    a.Start();

    string output = a.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    a.WaitForExit();

    MessageBox.Show("DONE!");
}
catch
{
MessageBox.Show("error!");
}
```