# C++ run error with command sfc /scannow

Tags: c++

I'm new here and I wanted to write a C++ source code that executes the command:

```
sfc.exe /scannow
```

But it doesn't work. Windows-resource protection can't start repair service.

I'm a student and I'm in my 10th grade and I do not have computer science at school, so I wanted to ask the question here.

Here is my code excerpt:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    system("sfc.exe /scannow");
}
```

The compiler brings no errors.
I am using the GNU/GCC compiler, Windows 10 1803 and Code::Blocks(IDE)

I hope you can understand it :)

Comment: i run the .exe as admin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using 64 bit system but your compiler is 32 bit means you will get this error. If you are using visual studio c++ and your pc is 64 bit system means change the platform to 64 bit.

For more information, ref this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/20872354/6599346

Answer (score 1):

Your code works, if you delete the `#` before `main()` and `using namespace` and just for completion I added `return 0;` at the end.

Code:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    system("sfc.exe /scannow"); 
    return 0;
}
```

Run the code with administrator rights and everything should be okay.

Comment: No, it works not. error Windows resource protection could not start the repair service, but thanks

Comment: @lucki1000 Mhm, I think you dont have a problem with your code then, you might have a problem within windows. Have your tried to fix this message? For example:   [1]: https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/fixed-windows-resource-protection-could-not-start-the-repair-service-sfc-error/

Comment: I have already tried other things, but if I start the cmd as admin then I can command use successful